# Why wouldn't some vertices move with a bone?

Tags: rigging

After many trials and errors, I came to the conclusion that I am unable to fix this problem.

### Trials and Errors

Almost everything used to work fine in the beginning. The only exception would be that my mesh's body would slightly deform while moving the right arm.

After many hours, I thought I had finally found the fix by removing some faces inside the model. That fixed the deforming problem but made it so that the right hand would be the only thing to gain weight when doing automatic weights.

After manually changing the weight to 0 the hand wouldn't move at all. I tried making a new arm with new bones, but that still didn't fix the problem.

I then removed half of my model and mirrored it again, symmetrized the bones and now some vertices don't move even though that arm moves perfectly fine.

Here's my .blend file:

[image]

Comment: For the moment, 2 vertices of your right arm are not assigned to any vertex group, you can assign them to the vertex group called ForeArm.R or parent the whole character With Automatic Weights again and it seems to work rather fine, I'm not sure what's the problem actually   ;)

Comment: You also have objects with unapplied scale, and your rig is 42m tall. You probably want to fix all that now before having it all tangled with a rig. Ctrl A menu is your friend.

Comment: @JohnEason, that should be the answer. I don't think it is good practice to answer questions in comments. Comments cannot be up-voted(in the same way), or down-voted. I mean that is  worth an upvote and I think it is *the* answer to the question, but what if it was a bad answer?.. Also it cannot be accepted as the solution, which I think it should be and possibly would be...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Ok. I'll post that as an answer this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it quickest to reset everything and start from scratch with other people's models so:

Select your model and use <kbd>ALT-P</kbd> to unparent it from the armature. (Not strictly necessary, but:) On the <kbd>Object Data</kbd> tab, clear the <kbd>Vertex Groups</kbd> with <kbd>Delete all Groups</kbd> on the dropdown.

[image]

The scale is correct on all your objects except the armature, so select that and <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> > <kbd>Scale</kbd> in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode to reset it.

Now select your model, Shift-select the armature and use <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> > <kbd>With Automatic Weights</kbd>.

[image]

You should now find that everything works correctly in <kbd>Pose</kbd> mode.

For completeness, I'd reset your <kbd>3D</kbd><kbd>Cursor</kbd> to the World Origin with <kbd>Shift-C</kbd> and change the Transform Pivot Point back to <kbd>Median Point</kbd> to make posing your model easier. I'd also delete all the keyframes in the Timeline with <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>Delete</kbd> and start again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It did work... However, the problem had moved from ForeArm.R to LowerLeg.R

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean. I suspect the topology of your object is confusing the parenting code with automatic weights. If you go into edit mode on the model and select (e.g.) LowerLeg.R in the Vertex Group list, choosing 'Select' below the list will show all the vertices that are controlled by that bone. It's a bit tedious if you need to do it for every bone, but you can then click outside the model to deselect everything, Shift-select the vertices which shouldn't be controlled by that bone and then click 'Remove' below the vertex group list.